# Iterate method list in Scala

Tags: scala, loops, methods, iteration

I'm just getting started in Scala (was using Python as a primary language for quite some time now), and I'm unable to figure out how to iterate a list of methods and call each method.

In Python I would do it as:

```
>>> def a():
...     return "a"
... 
>>> def b():
...     return "b"
... 
>>> c=[a,b]
>>> for i in c:
...     i()
... 
'a'
'b'
```

How do I do the same in Scala? So far, I have:

```
scala> def a = {
     | "a";
     | }
a: String

scala> def b = {
     | "b";
     | }
b: String

scala> val z = List(a,b)
z: List[String] = List(a, b)
```

But I'm unable to iterate over this. I tried using foreach, but I'm unsure how to call the functions

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like when you add `a` and `b` to the list, the def is evaluated and the result is stored in the list

```
scala> def a = "strA"
a: String

scala> def b = "strB"
b: String

scala> val z = List(a ,b )
z: List[String] = List(strA, strB)
```

You can transform a method (`def`) to a function by putting a `_` at the end (I think it's called ETA expansion)

```
scala> val z = List(a _ ,b _)
z: List[() => String] = List(<function0>, <function0>)

scala> z.foreach(f => println(f())) // for each function f, call it 
strA
strB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
def a = "a"
def b = "b"
def c = List(a,b)
c foreach (println(_))
```

> scala> c foreach (println(_))

a b